# Why use an integer to store 4 chars? Any practical benefits?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I know how to store 4 chars in a single integer.

My question is more to understand why is this useful?

**Any real-world practical examples** would help a lot.

Comment: Perhaps data compression, structure packing? These are especially useful in embedded environments where RAM is very constrained.

Comment: Also, some SIMD (single instruction, multiple data) processor instructions can operate on 4 chars as a single 32 bit integer blob, thus 4 operations in one tick.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.mikroe.com/blog/packed-structures-make-memory-feel-safe . Another point to make is that when you declare 4 chars, in RAM they need to be aligned, thus you have padding between, whereas packing them in an int, there is less or no padding.

Comment: @john: but if I am storing 4 chars in an integer, I know on the current architecture that they are the same size at the end. So RAM usage should be the same right? The SIMD example is however really interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @john: chars are *not* aligned in memory as they take 1 byte. That is, a structure defined as char a, b, c, d; will take 4 bytes exactly in memory.

Comment: This was common on the old Amiga OS with [Interchange File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interchange_File_Format) where chunks were identified by four-byte integers usually made up of four characters. Some modern file-formats still use similar structure.

Comment: I was hesitating to close vote for "Too broad" or "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: When you say they are the same size, you mean when you declare 4 chars, they take the same amount of RAM as an int without padding between on your arch? If so, then you can ignore the benefits of using less RAM.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: why is this too broad? I want to understand why we would *need* to store 4 chars in a single integer. Padding is not the answer IMHO. RAM is not an answer neither.

Comment: @john: there is no padding for chars. If you create a structure containing 4 chars, it will be 4 bytes in size, exactly. Try printf("%zu", sizeof(struct{char a, b, c, d;}));

Comment: @Korchkidu It is usually faster to iterate on larger chunk of memory. The exact optimal size may vary depending on the system. Moreover, `char` should be auto-promoted to `int` when performing a comparison: you might as well compare `int` directly.

Comment: I guess I don't need to mention that when you create packet frames and send them over a communication channel, you want to pack as much data as possible.

Comment: When you pack the chars in a struct indeed, you may end up with less or no padding. Declaring them in a function may introduce padding and alignments.

Comment: @Korchkidu Padding can be added at will by a compiler. Even between characters in a structure like you show. There's nothing in the C specification prohibiting padding between or after any fields. The only requirement is that the first member must begin at offset 0 (no padding before the first member).

Comment: I now think this question is too broad and it moves into a discussion. @Jabberwocky, is it time to close it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: in the point 6.2.6.2, it seems that padding concerns integer types except unsigned chars.

Comment: @john: why close? I am precisely asking for practical, real-world examples. The SIMD example may be useful. But others are more theoretical and debatable IMHO. Still, my question is really specific and clear.

Comment: Section 6.2.6.2 talks about bit-level padding, not the byte-level padding @Someprogrammerdude refers to

Comment: @Korchkidu That section isn't about structure padding, but about (possible) extra padding bits in the binary representation of the integers themselves.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: ok, thanks. Not sure to understand the difference though. I will check again. Thanks again.

Comment: This should be closed as it is too broad. The real world applications depend on the architecture you're on, and your constraints.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I do appreciate you trying to figure out the benefits of packing, however for an answer to be provided, you need more specificity.

Comment: Even if there aren't explicit SIMD instructions, some operator types still allow to execute more than one operation at once, such as AND, OR, XOR, tests for equality of all or inequality of any byte, ...

Answer (score 1):

Several operating systems and file formats used such values as "magic numbers":

- As @SomeProgrammerDude commented, the Amiga OS in its [Interchange File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interchange_File_Format).
- [PalmOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm_OS) used such values as identifiers for database, resource and record types. I think this was heavily influenced from the old MacOS.
- Some file formats like AVI, ANI and WAV use the [Resource Interchange File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format) as their basis.
- Apple's [Audio Interchange File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Interchange_File_Format) is also based on IFF.
- Since the old days of MS-DOS all EXE files (and DLL and...) have a [MZ-Signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable) as their first 16 bit value. (Well, not directly 4 characters, but 2 characters.)

*Please add more usages and/or correct this answer.*